# Exit Loop if `all Matches` are found

Tags: excel, vba

Using below code to `Match a range` on sheet "Auto" against a range on specific sheets on the same workbook.
If a match found, then some values will be inserted on that specific Sheets.
Practically, There will not be any duplicate matches, so I need to exit the main Loop if **all matches** are found.
**e.g** values **111** and **222** are found on sheets `"North"` and sheet `"central"` receptively,
So there is no need to search for a match on the other sheets,`so the need to exit loop`.
in advance,grateful for any useful help comment and answers.

```
Option Explicit
Option Compare Text

    Sub Run_Modified()
    
         Dim Auto_Data As Range: Set Auto_Data = Sheets("Auto").Range("A2:A21")
             
         Dim ws As Worksheet
    For Each ws In Sheets(Array("North", "Central", "Onshore", "South"))  'exit this Loop if all below Match are found
       
         Dim WorkOrder As Range: Set WorkOrder = ws.Range("B3:B250")
    
         Dim cell As Object, Match_A As Variant
         For Each cell In WorkOrder
     Match_A = Application.Match(cell.value, Auto_Data, 0)
          If Not IsError(Match_A) Then
             cell.Offset(, 6).Resize(1, 3).value = Array("Close", Now, ws.name)
          End If
               
        Next cell
        
     Next ws 'I need to exit this Loop if all Matches are found
    
    End Sub
```

Comment: What **all matches are found** should mean? Please, better explain this aspect. You try talking about 111 and 222, as an example, but your code iterates in a range of 20 cells...

Comment: Should we understand that if all 20 values of `Auto_Data`  range have a match, independent of iterated sheets  number, the loop should be exited?

Comment: @FaneDuru ,yes your understood is correct

Comment: I deleted my answer, I did not down voted your question. Probably, you have some 'friends' inside the community. I did not like your way of commenting below my answer, but it is  not my way to down vote a question. Even if it (the question) deserves it. Your question does not have any problem, according to my taste. If I could down vote some comments, probably I should try that... I am sometimes the single one answering questions which do not provide a piece of code. Mentioning to OP that it is an exception.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the idea of this answer is fully credits to @FaneDuru  
As stated on question that there are `no duplicate matches`.
So, the answer is to **compare** the number of matched values `against` count of (Range of match) `Auto_Data`.
If the result is equal each other ,that is means all values are matched and no need to complete the rest of both Loops.

```
Sub Run_Modified_1()

     Dim Auto_Data As Range: Set Auto_Data = Sheets("Auto").Range("A2:A21")
         
     Dim ws As Worksheet
For Each ws In Sheets(Array("North", "Central", "Onshore", "South"))
     Dim WorkOrder As Range: Set WorkOrder = ws.Range("B3:B250")

     Dim cell As Object, Match_A As Variant, k As Long
     For Each cell In WorkOrder
 Match_A = Application.Match(cell.value, Auto_Data, 0)
      If Not IsError(Match_A) Then
         cell.Offset(, 6).Resize(1, 3).value = Array("Close", Now, ws.name)
         k = k + 1
         If k = WorksheetFunction.CountA(Auto_Data) Then Exit Sub
      End If
    Next cell
 Next ws
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

`Exit For` is your friend.

If I understand you correctly this should be the part where you have to insert it:

```vb
If Not IsError(Match_A) Then
    cell.Offset(, 6).Resize(1, 3).value = Array("Close", Now, ws.name)
    exit for
End If
```

If there is a match on the sheet, data will be inserted and the `For each cell`-loop will be exited.

Next sheet will be handled.

Comment: **not working**, it exit after `first match`. I need to exist Loop after all matches